# css navigation submenu list-style-type: none not working

Tags: css, navigation

I'm working with the navigation bar in which

list-style-type: none for ul li ul li

is not working.

Here is my css code:

```
nav{
height: 32px;
line-height: 32px;
background: #3B5998;
padding: 0 20px 0 300px;
}

nav a{
list-style-type: none !important;
}

nav h1{
position: absolute;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

nav ul, nav ul li{
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
padding: 0;
}

nav ul li{
float: left;
display: block;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
}

nav ul li a:link, a:visited{
font-size: 13px;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:300;
line-height:18px;
letter-spacing:0px;
color: #CCCCCC;
text-decoration: none;
background-position:0 13px;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
color:#FFFFFF;
background-image:url(../images/link_bg.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:0 13px;
}

nav ul li ul{
position: absolute;
width: 160px;
left: -20px;
background: #FFF;
padding: 0px;
border: solid 1px #2E4B88;
border-top: none;
line-height: 26px;
z-index: 1000;
list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li ul li{
float: none;
display: block;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:link, nav ul li ul li a:visited{
color: #444;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0px;
clear: both;
border-bottom: solid 1px #DEDEDE;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover{
color: #3B5998;
}
```

and the html code:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./introduction/">Introduction</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="./introduction/ykrf/">YKRF Leadership Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./introduction/yonsei/">Yonsei University</a></li>
        <li><a href="./introduction/keio/">Keio University</a></li>
        <li><a href="./introduction/rikkyo/">Rikkyo University</a></li>
        <li><a href="./introduction/fudan/">Fudan University</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./forums/">Past Forums</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./forumbefore2008/">Before 2008</a></li>
        <li><a href="./forum2008/">2008 Shanghai</a></li>
        <li><a href="./forum2009/">2009 Seoul</a></li>
        <li><a href="./forum2010/">2010 Tokyo</a></li>
        <li><a href="./forum2011/">2011 Fudan</a></li>
        <li><a href="./forum2012/">2012 Seoul</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
       </ul>
 </nav>
```

So, in the ul with class submenu, all li's have 1. before it. Even if I set list-style-type: none for ul li ul li.

Where exactly should I set the css properties in order to remove 1. ?

The website is in http://wafflemaker.kr/ykrf/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have below css that is affecting whole css.

```
li li:before {
    content: counter(item, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

at `forum2011.css (line 20)`

Comment: Thanks!! Bad bug .. I never knew it.

Answer (score 0):

In your linked site list-style is in indeed set to none, and is not being overriden. The `1.` that appears before each item is actually coming form a `content` property in CSS on line 20-24 of form2011.css file. In order to override it, simple add this rule:

```
nav ul li ul li { content: ''; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li li:before {
    content: counter(item, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

this add the number to your menu

try removing or commenting that code from line 20 of forum2011.css. it will work

Answer (score 0):

Define your **`submenu li:before`** `content:"" ;` **none**

AS LIKE THIS **Define** this `css` in your **style-sheet**

```
.submenu li:before {
content: "";
}
```

### -----------------

Second Option is this

Define this `css` IN your `stylesheet`

**as like this**

```
nav li:before {
content: "";
}
```